# How to simulate a quantum walk with decoherence?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, decoherence, quantum-walks

I'm trying to reproduce quantum walk with decoherence as shown in figure 3 in [V. M. Kendon, Phil. Trans. R. Soc. A, 364, 2006](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2006.1901) ([quant-ph/0609035](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0609035)).

I am able to reproduce quantum walk without decoherence. And the code is attached.

To reproduce quantum walk with decoherence, I am thinking following the formula
$$|\psi_{t+1}\rangle = (1-p)U|\psi_t\rangle + pMU|\psi_t\rangle$$
where $|\psi_t\rangle$ represents the state at $t$-th step, $U$ is the quantum-walk operator, and $M$ is a measurement operator modeling the decoherence, $p$ is a specified probability that decoherence occurs at each step.

However, I'm having a hard time determining the operator $M$. Any suggestions?

The MATLAB code for quantum walk without decoherence:

```
clearvars;  clc;    close all 

t = 100;   % number of steps
P = 2*t+1; % number of positions

% coins
c0 = [1, 0];
c1 = [0, 1];

C00 = c0'*c0;
C01 = c0'*c1;
C10 = c1'*c0;
C11 = c1'*c1;

C = [1 1; 1 -1]/sqrt(2); % coin operator, or just the Hadamard operator

% shift operation
shiftplus  = circshift(eye(P),1);
shiftminus = circshift(eye(P),-1);
S = kron(shiftplus, C00) + kron(shiftminus, C11);

% walk operation
U = S*kron(eye(P), C);

% initial condition
x0 = zeros(P,1);
x0(t+1) = 1;
psi0 = kron(x0, (c0+c1*1i)'/sqrt(2));

% evolution
psi = U^t*psi0;

% measurement
p = zeros(P,1);

for i = 1:P
    x = zeros(P,1);
    x(i) = 1;
    Mi = kron(x*x', eye(2));
    proj = Mi*psi;
    p(i) = sum(real(proj.*conj(proj)));
end

% plotting
x = (-t:t)';
plot(x(1:2:end),p(1:2:end))
```

Comment: did you have a look at the other related review paper by Kendon, https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0606016?

Comment: @glS Yes, I did check that. They use the density matrix. But I think the overall idea is pretty much the same, and the key to their approach is the _projection operator_, which is not quite clearly defined.

Comment: well, if you want to model decoherence, you generally want to use a density matrix formalism. Otherwise what exactly do you mean with "measurement operator" in your equation? If $M$ is not unitary than the output states stops being pure. I suppose you could use (renormalised) Kraus operators $A_a$ of the corresponding channel in place of $M$, but that would just amount to unraveling the dynamics. In other words, the evolution you get becomes stochastic: the meas outcome determines the "measurement operator" applied to the state, and thus the $M$ in your equation becomes a random variable

Comment: @glS Make sense. But if I were to adapt the density-operator formalism (as the eq.49 in the paper you cited), how should I determine the projection operator? It's not clearly defined in the paper.

Comment: I haven't read the paper, but that's probably because there isn't a unique choice. It depends on what kind of noise you want to consider, which depends on what's the overall objective. Also on the way you plan to actually solve the dynamics (i.e. you stick to Markovian evolutions? You consider the classical unravelings?). There's plenty of things that can be done. You might want to have a look at some related papers to get a better idea, e.g. from some googling https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.06676 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.08652 seem relevant

Comment: did you manage to get your code working? if so, could you post it?